# Tell Swagger that the request body can be a single object or a list of objects

Tags: scala, rest, swagger, openapi

I am using Swagger with Scala to document my REST API. I want to enable bulk operations for POST, PUT and DELETE and want the same route to accept either a single object or a collection of objects as body content.

Is there a way to tell Swagger that a param is either a list of values of type A or a single value of type A?

Something like varargs for REST.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell Swagger that a param is either a list of values of type A or a single value of type A?

This depends on whether you use OpenAPI 3.0 or OpenAPI (Swagger) 2.0.

OpenAPI uses an extended subset of JSON Schema to describe body payloads. JSON Schema provides the `oneOf` and `anyOf` keywords to define multiple possible schemas for an instance. However, different versions of OpenAPI support different sets of JSON Schema keywords.

**OpenAPI 3.0** supports `oneOf` and `anyOf`, so you can describe such an object or array of object as follows:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

components:
  schemas:
    A:
      type: object
    Body:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/A'
        - type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/A'
```

In the example above, `Body` can be either object `A` or an array of objects `A`.

**OpenAPI (Swagger) 2.0** [does not support `oneOf` and `anyOf`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1056). The most you can do is use a [typeless schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328994/113116):

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

definitions:
  A:
    type: object
  # Note that Body does not have a "type"
  Body:
    description: Can be object `A` or an array of `A`
```

This means the `Body` can be anything - an object (any object!), an array (containing any items!), also a primitive (string, number, etc.). There is no way to define the exact `Body` structure in this case. You can only describe this verbally in the `description`.

You'll need to use OpenAPI 3.0 to define your exact scenario.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up. It is a recognized drawback that hopefully will receive some attention in the future as it does hinder proper documentation of existing APIs like GeoJSON. This link adds to the discussion: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/57 
I think for now I will just go with properly documenting the "List or single object" style in words.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's possible to annotate your API like that with Swagger. But my suggestion is to simplify/unify your API. If you think about it, if you're going to support bulk (meaning an array of objects) then there's no reason to have a special treatment of a single object. You should just change the API to always take an array and if someone wants to do a single object then thats just the case of a list with a single element `object :: Nil`.

Comment: ... and it costs exactly two chars: `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send object, just remove @OA\Items()

```
 *   @OA\RequestBody(
 *      required=true,
 *      @OA\JsonContent(
 *         ref="#/components/schemas/Brand"
 *      )
 *   ),
```