# How to define a mixed-type array (with different element types) in OpenAPI 2.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I trying to map the following JSON to an OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0) YAML definition, and I am not sure how to set mixed array types into my schema:

```json
{
  "obj1": [
     "string data",
     1
    ]
}
```

Now, my OpenAPI definition has:

```yaml
schema:
  object1:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
```

but this doesn't allow integers inside the array.

Is there a way to define a mixed type array?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer depends on which version of the OpenAPI Specification you use.

#### OpenAPI 3.1

`type` can be a list of types, so you can write your schema as:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

obj1:
  type: array
  items:
    type: [string, integer]
    # or if nulls are allowed:
    # type: [string, integer, 'null']
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0.x

Mixed types are supported in OpenAPI 3.0 using `oneOf` / `anyOf` and optionally `nullable: true` to also allow nulls.

```yaml
# openapi: 3.0.1

obj1:
  type: array
  items:
    oneOf:
      - type: string
        nullable: true  # If nulls are allowed
      - type: integer
```

#### OpenAPI 2.0

OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0) does not really support mixed-type array and parameters. The most you can do is to use a [typeless schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328994/113116) `{}` for `items`, which means the items can be anything (except `null`) – numbers, objects, strings, etc. You cannot specify the exact types for `items`, but you can add an `example` of an array with different item types.

```yaml
# swagger: '2.0'

obj1:
  type: array
  items: {}  # <--- means "any type" (except null)
  example:
    - string data
    - 1
```

**Note:** Typeless schema `{}` can only be used in body parameters and response schemas. Path, header and form parameters require a primitive `type` for array items.

Comment: where exactly in the spec is this specified? I can't find it in the spec and the editor.swagger.io still considers it an error and doesn't allow me to specifiy multiple types for a property in this way

Comment: @CharonME OpenAPI schema definitions are based on [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/), with some limitations. If you use OpenAPI 3.1, use https://editor-next.swagger.io instead of https://editor.swagger.io.