# Schema object without a type attribute in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, jsonschema, swagger-2.0, openapi

Does a Schema object in Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 have to have the `type` attribute or not?

On the one hand, according to the JSON Schema Draft 4 spec, not specifying the `type` attribute is OK and means that the instance can be of any type (an object, an array or a primitive).

On the other hand, I've seen a lot of Swagger schemas which contain Schema objects without the `type` attribute, but with the `properties` attribute, which makes it clear that the schema author wants the instance to be a proper object (and doesn't want to accept arrays or primitive as valid values).

Are all those schemas incorrect? Or is `type: object` implied by the presence of `properties`? There's nothing in either the Swagger or the JSON Schema spec that says that is the case. In fact, I've seen comments that explicitly say that's NOT the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like in JSON Schema, OpenAPI schema objects [do not require a `type`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1388#issuecomment-339061316), and you are correct in that no `type` means [any type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328994/113116).

"Type-specific" keywords such as `properties`, `items`, `minLength`, etc. **do not enforce a type** on the schema. It works the other way around – when an instance is validated against a schema, these keywords only apply when the instance is of the corresponding type, otherwise they are ignored. Here's the relevant part of the [JSON Schema Validation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-4.1) spec:

> **4.1.  Keywords and instance primitive types**

> Some validation keywords only apply to one or more primitive types. When the primitive type of the instance cannot be validated by a given keyword, validation for this keyword and instance SHOULD succeed.

For example, consider this schema:

```yaml
Something:
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
  required: [id]
  minLength: 8
```

It's a valid schema, even though it combines object-specific keywords `properties` and `required` and string-specific keyword `minLength`. This schema means:

- If the instance is an object, it must have an integer property named `id`. For example, `{"id": 4}` and `{"id": -1, "foo": "bar"}` are valid, but `{}` and `{"id": "ACB123"}` are not.
- If the instance is a string, it must contain at least 8 characters. `"Hello, world!"` is valid, but `""` and `abc` are not.
- Any instances of other types are valid - `true`, `false`, `-1.234`, `[]`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `[1, "foo", true]`, etc. In OpenAPI 3.x, untyped schemas also [allow `null` values](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/proposals/003_Clarify-Nullable.md#does-an-untyped-schema-without-a-type-keyword-allow-null-values-by-default-what-effect-if-any-does-nullable-true-have-on-an-untyped-schema).

If there are tools that infer the `type` from other keywords (for example, handle schemas with no `type` but with `properties` as always objects), then these tools are not exactly following the OpenAPI Specification and JSON Schema.

Bottom line: If a schema must always be an object, add `type: object` explicitly. Otherwise you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That's how I understand the JSON Schema spec as well. But, even the Swagger code generator (available in the Swagger Editor) doesn't handle this properly. 

For example, if you open the petstore swagger schema, remove `type: object` from the `Tag` object schema and then generate a client (I tried both Go and Java), the code doesn't allow for Tags to be anything but objects (e.g. the `Pet` class contains an array called `tags`, which can only contain `Tag` objects, not primitives or arrays.

Comment: @MarkoLukša: Well that's a Codegen issue. Feel free to file a bug [Codegen repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues).