# OpenAPI Path Parameters referencing Component Properties

Tags: openapi

Let's say I have some simple Order > OrderLines > Product Data Model in an OpenAPI document.
The Components part would look like this:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Order:
      required:
        - orderId
      properties:
        orderId:
          type: integer
        orderlines:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/OrderLine'
    OrderLine:
      required:
        - orderLineId
        - product
        - price
      properties:
        orderLineId:
          type: integer
        product:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Product'
        price:
          type: integer
    Product:
      required:
        - productId
        - name
      x-keys:
        - productId
      properties:
        productId:
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string
```

When building a path to define an api to get a specific OrderLine on an Order, this would look like this:

```
paths:
    /orders/{orderId}/orderlines/{orderLineId}:
        get:
            operationId: getOrderLine
            parameters:
               - in: path
                 name: orderId
                 schema:
                    type: integer
                 required: true
               - in: path
                 name: orderLineId
                 schema:
                    type: integer
                 required: true
```

Now, the defined orderId parameters actually refers to the orderId property of the Order Component. And the same goes for parameter orderLineId which refers to the orderLineId property of Component OrderLine.

So is it possible to actually refer to these properties in the parameter definition instead of duplicating the type information of the properties?

I mean is it somehow possible to do something like this:

```
paths:
    /orders/{orderId}/orderlines/{orderLineId}:
        get:
            operationId: getOrderLine
            parameters:
               - in: path
                 name: orderId
                 $ref: #components/schemas/Order/properties/orderId
                 required: true
               - in: path
                 name: orderLineId
                 $ref: #components/schemas/OrderLine/properties/orderLineId
                 required: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, always add `type: object` to your object definitions; the `properties` keyword alone is not enough to indicate the object type. The `type` is not inferred from other keywords, and [no `type` actually means "any type"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47390723/113116).

As for your question - sure, it's possible to `$ref` individual property definitions. Your example is almost correct, you just need to:

1. Put the `$ref` inside the parameter `schema`.
2. Replace `#components` with `#/components`.
3. Enclose the reference values (`#/components/...`) in quotes to prevent them from being parsed as YAML comments.

```yaml
paths:
    /orders/{orderId}/orderlines/{orderLineId}:
        get:
            operationId: getOrderLine
            parameters:
               - in: path
                 name: orderId
                 schema:
                   $ref: '#/components/schemas/Order/properties/orderId'
                 required: true
               - in: path
                 name: orderLineId
                 schema:
                   $ref: '#/components/schemas/OrderLine/properties/orderLineId'
                 required: true
```

However, referencing property definitions is uncommon, and some tools may have problems handling such references. It's best to define separate schemas for all definitions you want to `$ref`:

```yaml
components:    
  schemas:
    OrderId:        # <-------
      type: integer
    OrderLineId:    # <-------
      type: integer

    Order:
      type: object
      required:
        - orderId
      properties:
        orderId:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OrderId'      # <-------
        ...
    OrderLine:
      type: object
      required:
        - orderLineId
        - product
        - price
      properties:
        orderLineId:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OrderLineId'  # <-------
        ...

paths:
    /orders/{orderId}/orderlines/{orderLineId}:
        get:
            operationId: getOrderLine
            parameters:
               - in: path
                 name: orderId
                 schema:
                   $ref: '#/components/schemas/OrderId'      # <-------
                 required: true
               - in: path
                 name: orderLineId
                 schema:
                   $ref: '#/components/schemas/OrderLineId'  # <-------
                 required: true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough and clear explanation!