# How do I interpret this OpenAPI array definition with the "properties" keyword?

Tags: arrays, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

Conside this OpenAPI schema:

```yaml
Units:
  type: array
  properties:
    empty:
      type: boolean
  items:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Unit'
```

Swagger Editor renders it as follows:

[image: result in right schema pane in Swagger Editor]

How should I interpret the 'empty' property ? Why is it seen as an ordered map?

Normally an array has `items` but no direct `properties` in it.

Answer (score 1):

In this schema, the `properties` section is effectively ignored. The `properties` section has effect only for `type: object` and in [typeless schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47390723/113116), but it's not used with arrays. So this definition is equivalent to:

```yaml
Units:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Unit'
```

The "OrderedMap" text in Swagger Editor's model renderer can be considered a display bug. Feel free to open an issue for this here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues