# How to write an OpenAPI (Swagger) definition for this field with multiple types?

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm writing an OpenAPI definition for the `params` field which is an object and contains a field called `name`, which is of string type by default but can be of any type, e.g. integer, number, boolean, string, or array of string, boolean, number, integer.

**params: {
    [name: string]: int | string | number | boolean | int[] | string[] | number[] | boolean[]
  }**

How can I define such a field in OpenAPI?

I have tried the following

```yaml
  params:
    description: Simple parameters map
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      name:
        type: object
        oneOf:
          - type: string
          - type: boolean
          - type: integer
          - type: number
          - type: array
            items:
              - string
              - integer
              - number
              - boolean
```

but this produces the following syntax error:

> Should not include additional properties name.

Comment: What's the field name and type, exactly? Where is this field used - in the query string, request body, etc.? The more details, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks Helen, Actually i have mentioned the field name in the question i.e *params* which is an object and includes field called *name* which is of string type by default and it could be of any type like mention below:. Integer, number, boolean string or  array of string, boolean, number, integer. it could be anything. This field is used particularly in the definition of one entity which is send as request body further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *params* which is an object and includes field called *name* which is of string type by default and it could be of any type like mention below:. Integer, number, boolean string or array of string, boolean, number, integer. **it could be anything.**

"[Can be anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328994/113116)" is defined by not specifying the `type` at all. But in this case, possible "anything" values include objects and array of objects, which you didn't mention.

```yaml
params:
  description: Simple parameters map
  type: object
  properties:
    name: {}

    # OR if you want to add a description, use
    # name:
    #   description: Can be anything
```

However, if "anything" means just the specific types you listed, you need `anyOf`. Note that `anyOf` is supported in OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) and is not supported in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 (`swagger: "2.0"`).

```yaml
# openapi: 3.0.0

params:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      anyOf:
        - type: string
        - type: integer
        - type: number
        - type: boolean
        - type: array
          items:
            type: string
        - type: array
          items:
            type: integer
        - type: array
          items:
            type: number
        - type: array
          items:
            type: boolean
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Helen. Actually, Helen, My swagger supported OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0.  And it is not supported anyOf so what should I supposed to write in place of anyOf in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0.
Bdw Thanks for the answer it is really helpful for me, It would be great if you tell me what swagger2.0 supports.

And anything mentioned above, you got it right its just the specific one that i have mentioned.

Comment: In OpenAPI 2.0 the most you can do is to define the property as typeless (`name: {}`) as shown in the first part of my answer.